# For subgroups $H_{1,2,3} \lneq G$ so that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^3H_i = G$ show: $[G : H_i]=2$

Tags: group-theory

Let $H_1,H_2,H_3 \lneq G$ be groups such that $\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^3H_i = G$. Show that $\forall 1\leq i \leq 3\ [G : H_i]=2$

For three different numbers $1\leq i,j,k \leq 3$, if for some $H_i \leq H_j$ then $H_i \cup H_j \cup H_k = H_j\cup H_k = G$. The union of two subgroups is a subgroup only if one is a subgroup of the other, so we get $H_k = G$, while it's given that $H_k \lneq G$.
**So no $H_i$ is a subgroup of another $H_j$.**

If so, then for the union $(H_i \cup H_j) \cup H_k$ to be a group, it's required that $H_k=<(H_i \cup H_j)-(H_i\cap H_j)> (= <H_i \Delta H_j>)$. But then, if $h_1 \in (H_i \cap H_j),\ h_2 \in (H_i \Delta H_j) \subset H_k$, let's say $h_2 \in H_j$ (it belongs to either $H_j$ or $H_i$), then also $h_2^{-1}, h_2h_1 \in H_i \Delta H_j \subset H_k \Longrightarrow h_1 \in H_k$. So we got $H_i,H_j \leq H_k$, but we showed that this contradicts with G being their union.

Is there a problem with the question, or did I miss something?

Comment: Your formula for $H_k$, after "If so", is not right. Try to take an example: $G=\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2$, $H_1=\mathbb{Z}_2\times 1$, $H_2=1\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_3=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: You argued that $h_1\in H_i\cap H_j$ implies $h_1\in H_k$, so $H_i\cap H_j\subseteq H_k$. But then you stated this conclusion as $H_i, H_j\leq H_k$, which is not the same.

Comment: @LuizCordeiro But $H1$ is Not a set, as $e=(0,0) \not\in H_1$. Same for $H_2$.

Comment: @galra You're right, I mixed my notations in the middle of the comment. I meant, if $\mathbb{Z}_2=\{0,1\}$, take $H_1=\mathbb{Z}_2\times 0$, $H_2=0\times\mathbb{Z}_2$ and $H_3=\{(0,0),(1,1)\}$.

Comment: I see. My mistake was that $H_k$ doesn't have to include $k,l:\ k \in (H_i - H_j),\ l \in (H_j - H_i)$, but only the product $kl$. Thanks!

Comment: I have just noticed that the duplicate question assumes that $G$ is finite, which is unnecessary. There is a detailed solution by Arturo Magidin in an answer to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/149025

Comment: You might want to check http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900550/union-of-subgroups-is-subgroup for more interesting information.