# $A$, $B$, $H$ are subgroups of $G$ and $H\subseteq A\cup B$, prove that $H\subseteq A$ or $H\subseteq B$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $A$, $B$, $H$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $H\subseteq A\cup B$. Prove that $H\subseteq A$ or $H\subseteq B$.

Any hint would be appreciated!

Comment: The alternative is that $H$ contains elements $a\in A\setminus B$ and $b\in B\setminus A$. Can you see why $ab$ isn't in either $A$ or $B$?

Comment: Does $\subseteq$ mean subset or subgroup here? I suppose subgroup?

Comment: @user281392 thx for your help! I guess I'm still new to algebra...

Comment: @marshal craft A∪B is not necessarily a subgroup right?

Comment: Hmm I guess it is subset. I've never seen $\cup$ used for group but underlying set. I've seen both $\subset \subseteq \lt \le$ for subgroup however.

Comment: Not a clue why this question if put on hold. The question is equivalent to the statement that a group cannot be the (set-theoretic) union of two of its subgroups. Research has been done if "two" can be replaced by "three" or any natural number greater than 2, see also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/900550/union-of-subgroups-is-subgroup The matter is highly non-trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If not, then $H$ isn't a subset of $A$ and is not a subset of $B$. Thus, since $H\subseteq A\cup B$, there are $a\in H\cap (A-B)$ and $b\in H\cap (B-A)$. Since $H$ is a group, $a*b\in H$. However, $a*b\not\in A\cup B$. Why? If $a*b\in A$, then $b=a^{-1}*a*b\in A$ since $A$ is closed under the group operation, and this a contradiction. Similarly, $a*b\not\in B$. So $a*b\in H-(A\cup B)$, a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

If there were an $a\in H,A$ and $b \in H,B$ then the product $ab$ is surely in $H$ but it is not in $A \cup B$ because if it were in $A$ then $b=a^{-1}ab$ would be in $A$ and $A$ would equal $B$.